# Resaltar (mostrar activo) criterio de orden en tabla HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, tablas

Tengo una tabla HTML que consta de 2 columnas: Nombre y Ciudad.
Esta tabla la ordeno (con javascript) haciendo click en el encabezado de la columna, de la siguiente manera;

```js
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
    var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
        tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
        i;
    reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
    tr = tr.sort(function (a, b) { // sort rows
        return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
            * (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
                .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
               );
    });
    for(i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
    var th = table.tHead, i;
    th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
    if (th) i = th.length;
    else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
    while (--i >= 0) (function (i) {
        var dir = 1;
        th[i].addEventListener('click', function () {sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))});
    }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
    parent = parent || document.body;
    var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'), i = t.length;
    while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function () {makeAllSortable();};
```

```css
        .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-color:#000000;border-spacing:0; width:100%}
.tg td{background-color:#EBF5FF;border-color:#507ABE;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;color:#444;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{background-color:#507ABE;border-color:#507ABE;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;color:#fff;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;overflow:hidden;padding:10px 5px;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-kpbb{background-color:#507abe;border-color:inherit;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
.tg .tg-ycr8{background-color:#f0f5ff;border-color:#000000;text-align:left;vertical-align:top}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Ciudad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>Nombre 1</td><td>Ciudad 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nombre 2</td><td>Ciudad 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nombre 3</td><td>Ciudad 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nombre 4</td><td>Ciudad 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

La consulta es:

Cómo hago para dejar "resaltado", "activo" o identificar de alguna forma el último criterio de orden usado (Nombre o Ciudad, ascendente o descendente)?

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente:

- Usar el [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) de la `table` para guardar el índice de la última columna clic-eada.
- Al hacer clic sobre una columna:

  - Primero verificamos si previamente se hizo clic en alguna y le sacamos los estilos aplicados.
  - Luego en base a la dirección de ordenamiento, aplicamos el estilo correspondiente.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function sortTable(table, col, reverse) {
  // ACA
  if (table.dataset.col !== undefined) {
    table.tHead.rows[0].cells[table.dataset.col].classList.remove('sortAsc', 'sortDesc');
  }
  table.dataset.col = col
  table.tHead.rows[0].cells[table.dataset.col].classList.add(reverse ? 'sortDesc' : 'sortAsc');
  ////////
  
      
  var tb = table.tBodies[0], // use `<tbody>` to ignore `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` rows
    tr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tb.rows, 0), // put rows into array
    i;
  reverse = -((+reverse) || -1);
  tr = tr.sort(function(a, b) { // sort rows
    return reverse // `-1 *` if want opposite order
      *
      (a.cells[col].textContent.trim() // using `.textContent.trim()` for test
        .localeCompare(b.cells[col].textContent.trim())
      );
  });
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; ++i) tb.appendChild(tr[i]); // append each row in order
}

function makeSortable(table) {
  var th = table.tHead,
    i;
  th && (th = th.rows[0]) && (th = th.cells);
  if (th) i = th.length;
  else return; // if no `<thead>` then do nothing
  while (--i >= 0)(function(i) {
    var dir = 1;
    th[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      sortTable(table, i, (dir = 1 - dir))
    });
  }(i));
}

function makeAllSortable(parent) {
  parent = parent || document.body;
  var t = parent.getElementsByTagName('table'),
    i = t.length;
  while (--i >= 0) makeSortable(t[i]);
}

window.onload = function() {
  makeAllSortable();
};
```

```css
.tg {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-color: #000000;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%
}

.tg td {
  background-color: #EBF5FF;
  border-color: #507ABE;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #444;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th {
  background-color: #507ABE;
  border-color: #507ABE;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  word-break: normal;
}

.tg th.sortAsc::after {
  content: "↑";
  color: #FFBA10;
}
.tg th.sortDesc::after {
  content: "↓";
  color: #FFBA10;
}

.tg .tg-kpbb {
  background-color: #507abe;
  border-color: inherit;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}

.tg .tg-ycr8 {
  background-color: #f0f5ff;
  border-color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<table class="tg">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th>Nombre</th>
      <th>Ciudad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr><td>Nombre 1</td><td>Ciudad 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nombre 2</td><td>Ciudad 2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nombre 3</td><td>Ciudad 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Nombre 4</td><td>Ciudad 2</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Referencias adicionales:

- [CSS > ::after](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/::after)

Comment: Gracias @Marcos.
Funcionó perfectamente a lo que pretendía.